# To add the following pair of combinatorials

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How to write sum of these combinatorials as one combination term

$$\binom{N-1}{y} + \binom{N-2}{y-1}$$

Comment: $^{n}C_r+^{n}C_{r-1}=^{n+1}C_r$

Comment: You can prove this identity from definition of combination.

Comment: That doesn't directly apply here, @Mann

Comment: Ah sorry, I almost didn't see!

Comment: The sum isn't always a (non-trivial) binomial. E.g., take $N=8$ and $y=3$; then the sum is ${7\choose 3}+{6\choose 2}$ $=35+15$ $=50$, and the latter only appears as $50\choose 1$. Are you sure you've written things down correctly?

Comment: A minus would make the things right it seems.

Answer (score 1):

The only way that I  see is, to write them in one combinatorial term, is to add a factor. Maybe it´s not exactly what you want.

It is

$\frac{k}{n-1}\cdot {{n-1} \choose k}={{n-2} \choose {k-1}}$

This can be seen by expressing the binomial coefficent as a fraction of products:

$\frac{k}{n-1}\cdot {{n-1} \choose k}=\frac{k}{n-1}\cdot \frac{1\cdot 2 \cdot \ldots \cdot (n-1) }{ 1 \cdot  \ldots \cdot k \cdot 1 \cdot \ldots \cdot (n-k-1) }$

Cancelling out k

$\frac{k}{n-1}\cdot {{n-1} \choose k}=\frac{1}{n-1}\cdot \frac{1\cdot 2 \cdot \ldots \cdot (n-1) }{ 1 \cdot  \ldots \cdot (k-1) \cdot 1 \cdot \ldots \cdot (n-k-1)}$

Cancelling out n-1

$\frac{k}{n-1}\cdot {{n-1} \choose k}=\frac{1}{1}\cdot \frac{1\cdot 2 \cdot \ldots \cdot (n-2) }{ 1 \cdot  \ldots \cdot (k-1) \cdot 1 \cdot \ldots \cdot (n-k-1)}$

$(k-1)+(n-k-1)=n-2 \checkmark$

Thus

$\left (1+\frac{k}{n-1} \right) \cdot {{n-1} \choose k}={{n-1} \choose k}+{{n-2} \choose {k-1}}$

Comment: This is a great help.....thanks,,,,